# Play AVCHD (.mts) in chrome (To work with a Chromecast)

Tags: google-chrome, video, chromecast

I generally use the Mozilla plugin from VLC in order to play local video content within a chrome tab.  This allows for casting to a Chromecast device.

Although VLC is able to play AVCHD files, the browser plugin does not.

I'm looking for a way to play AVCHD files in a chrome tab without converting them to another format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Videostream chromecast plugin plays all local video I've thrown at it so far including AVCHD (from cpu usage appears to transcode on the fly).

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/videostream-for-google-ch/cnciopoikihiagdjbjpnocolokfelagl?hl=en